# Undefined Method in Devise Routes with User ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Currently I have a typical devise installation but I've added user-id's to the routes that have a current_user available. But I'm getting the error stated below when trying to login to the service.

**Error**

```
NameError in Devise::SessionsController#create

undefined local variable or method `offers_path' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x007f0e80ec7a08>

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    offers_path
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users

resources :users do
  resources :offers do
    member do
       put :tourcomplete
    end   
  end
end
```

**Rake Routes**

```
 tourcomplete_user_offer PUT    /users/:user_id/offers/:id/tourcomplete(.:format) offers#tourcomplete
             user_offers GET    /users/:user_id/offers(.:format)                  offers#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/offers(.:format)                  offers#create
          new_user_offer GET    /users/:user_id/offers/new(.:format)              offers#new
         edit_user_offer GET    /users/:user_id/offers/:id/edit(.:format)         offers#edit
              user_offer GET    /users/:user_id/offers/:id(.:format)              offers#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/offers/:id(.:format)              offers#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/offers/:id(.:format)              offers#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/offers/:id(.:format)              offers#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                                  users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                  users#create
```

Not too sure if this is the best way to put user-id's within the logged in routes. Would love any help on this issue.

Comment: post the full error trace. Also, if the error is in your view, then post the view code too.

Comment: try changing it to `user_offers_path(resource)`

Comment: Added the full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your routes, you don't have any `offers_path` but you are trying to use that, that's why you are getting this error.

You should try using `user_offers_path` instead and the pass the `user` as the argument, something like this:

```
user_offers_path(@user)
```

Comment: Hi KM, I'm currently getting 

(No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"offers", :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_id] in my welcome_controller). 

Can I still use the above code?

Comment: you have to send the `user_id` in the params, and then grab the user like this: `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`, then: `user_offers_path(@user)`. Try this and let me know.